# Implement MVP pattern for file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms, mvp

I am new to the MVP pattern. I am not quite clear where to write the logic to upload a file to the server and then do some validation steps and database operations following the upload. Please advise.

```
public interface IPresenter
{
    void UploadFile(string fileName); //For simplicity, file name is passed;
                                      //it can be declared as a property  
}    

public interface IDefaultView
{
     void Upload();
}

public class DefaultPresenter : IPresenter
{
     protected DefaultPresenter() {}

     public DefaultPresenter(IDefaultView defaultview)
     {
        this.defaultView = defaultView;
     }

     public void UploadFile(string fileName)
     {
         //Do I need to write saving functionality here or call
         //defaultView.Upload(fileName)?
         //
         //From online articles, I have seen all business functionality written here.
         //But I think I will not be able to use System.Web in this layer.
     }
}

public partial class UploadExtract: IDefaultView    
{
    public void Upload(fileName)
    {                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `System.Web` in your business logic. And, in fact, you shouldn't.

You could code your controller to accept the file from the client and save it somewhere in the local server. Then, pass the file name to your business logic layer for further processing.

And your follow-up question:

> Q. I am reading the file into a memory stream. Is it advisable to pass
>   the memory stream to the presenter, perform the business logic in the
>   presenter, and finally set the file upload status in view?

Yes, that works too: pass the stream instead of the file name.